# Weblogic Stuck thread impacts other runnable threads in it

Tags: weblogic, jta, weblogic11g, java-threads

I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 with 8 managed servers configured with session timeout as 600 seconds. I have an issue with my application that when a session gets timed out in 600 seconds(I am receiving as STUCK alerts which is also configured) I am facing slowness in my application. My question is,

- Will all threads be impacted because of one STUCK thread(STUCK thread
  was due to DB transaction timeout)

I assume it will not be, but wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your application. In general no, but if for example the stuck thread is holding a lock on an object (database, file, etc.) called by other requests, these may be affected too. Also, depending on what the stuck thread is doing, it may use excessive resources (cpu, memory, disk, etc.). I suggest to investigate why the thread is taking so long and if it's possible to